# What does the following mean in PHP?

Tags: php, ip

what does the colon mean in php in the following example.

```
::1

if($host == "" || $ip == "::1")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are referring to the [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) adress of IPv6.

`::1` is a "shortcut" for `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`, which is the IPv6 version of `127.0.0.1` in IPv4.

The adress probably comes from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Answer (score 3):

Apache/PHP provides *::1* as the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` value when accessing the server locally (the full IP address would be 127.0.0.1).